# Azure devops REST API to add comment to specific line of code under commits

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there an ADO REST API to add a comment on a specific line of code in a commit. For example in the screenshot, you see I have manually added a comment "I want to add a comment to this commit using ADO REST API" on line-10

[image]

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an ADO REST API to add a comment on a specific line of code in a commit.

Yes. You can use the Rest API: [Pull Request Threads - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#comment-on-a-specific-file-in-the-pull-request) to add the comment to target line. You can define the rightFileEnd and rightFileStart in the request body.

**Rest API:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/threads?api-version=7.0
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "content": "Should we add a comment about what this value means?",
      "commentType": 1
    }
  ],
  "status": 1,
  "threadContext": {
    "filePath": "filename",
    "rightFileEnd": {
      "line": 10,
      "offset": 13
    },
    "rightFileStart": {
      "line": 10,
      "offset": 1
    }
  },
  "pullRequestThreadContext": {
    "changeTrackingId": 1,
    "iterationContext": {
      "firstComparingIteration": 1,
      "secondComparingIteration": 2
    }
  }
}
```